# GSL-config not found

Tags: apt

I am trying to install a simulator in ubuntu 16.04.2 and I get the following error:

```
CMake Error at cmake/modules/FindGSL.cmake:110 (MESSAGE): could not find gsl-config.  Please set it manually. 
GSL-CONFIG=GSL_CONFIG-NOTFOUND
CmakeLists.txt:93(find_package)

--configuring incomplete, errors occured!
```

Please, someone can help me with this error?

Answer (score 26):

You are missing the `libgsl-dev` package. This can be installed via the command line

```
sudo apt install libgsl-dev
```

Comment: If using 14.04, then consider `sudo apt-get install libgsl0ldbl` as `libgsl-dev` is not available for this version.

Comment: While not the system the OP specified, this helped me get where I needed to be on RedHat 7 so I'll add a note to try `sudo yum install gsl-devel` if that's your situation.

Comment: Thanks. Useful for RcppGSL R package. To be able to do in R: `install.packages('RcppGSL')`

Comment: For people on Mac, run [`brew install gsl`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55266014/7669319)

Comment: This works for Ubuntu 22.04 as well!